# Get all instances of a keyed service type in .NET 8

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, .net-8.0

Before keyed services were introduced in .NET 8 you could retrieve all of the instances of a class or interface with `IEnumerable<MyType> myTypes` like so:

**Program.cs**

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IProduct, Product1>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IProduct, Product2>();
```

**ProductsManager.cs**

```
public class ProductsManager {
    constructor(IEnumerable<IProduct> products) {} // products.Count = 2
}
```

However, this does not work anymore when you define them as keyed services:

**Program.cs**

```
builder.Services.AddKeyedSingleton<IProduct, Product1>("p1");
builder.Services.AddKeyedSingleton<IProduct, Product2>("p2");
```

**ProductsManager.cs**

```
public class ProductsManager {
    constructor(IEnumerable<IProduct> products) {} // products.Count = 0
}
```

So what is the equivalent of `IEnumerable<>` with Keyed services?

Comment: The short answer is there is no equivalent, but using a factory instead may be better.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I'm pretty sure calling `AddSingleton` for the same `IService` type either throws... or overwrites/replaces the last previous registration.

Comment: @Dai as far as I remember it overrides the "single" resolution (i.e. resolving `IProduct` will return the last one registered) but you still will be able to get both when resolving collection.

Comment: @Dai that might be true for pre-8.0 behavior. There were a bunch of DI changes with the 8.0 not being so sure this might be one of those.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77559201/

Answer (score 0):

Adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77559908/2501279):

```
var services = new ServiceCollection();
services.AddKeyedSingleton("A", new MyTest("A"));
services.AddKeyedSingleton("B", new MyTest("B"));

RegisterKeyedEnumerable<string, MyTest>(services);

void RegisterKeyedEnumerable<TKey, T>(ServiceCollection serviceCollection)
{
    var keys = serviceCollection
        .Where(sd => sd.IsKeyedService && sd.ServiceType == typeof(T))
        .Select(d => d.ServiceKey)
        .Select(k => (TKey)k)
        .ToList();

    serviceCollection.AddTransient<IEnumerableOfKeyd<T>>(p => keys
        .Select(k => p.GetRequiredKeyedService<T>(k)));
}

var sp = services.BuildServiceProvider();
var myTestClasses = sp.GetService<IEnumerableOfKeyd<MyTest>>();

interface IEnumerableOfKeyd<T> : IEnumerable<T>{}

record MyTest(string Name);
```

Also you can make generic registration of `IEnumerableOfKeyd` to improve the approach. Something to get you started:

```
// ...

services.AddSingleton<IServiceCollection>(services);
// todo split in two parts and register IEnumerableOfKeyd as transient:
services.AddSingleton(typeof(IEnumerableOfKeyd<>), typeof(EnumerableOfKeyd<>)); 
var sp = services.BuildServiceProvider();
var myTestClasses = sp.GetService<IEnumerableOfKeyd<MyTest>>();

// ...

class EnumerableOfKeyd<T> : IEnumerableOfKeyd<T>
{
    private List<T?> _services;

    public EnumerableOfKeyd(IServiceCollection serviceCollection, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _services = serviceCollection
            .Where(sd => sd.IsKeyedService && sd.ServiceType == typeof(T))
            .Select(d => d.ServiceKey)
            .Select(k => serviceProvider.GetRequiredKeyedService<T>(k))
            .ToList();
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator() => _services.GetEnumerator();

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();
}
```

See [the amazing answer by Steven](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77559901/2501279) for approach which handles the lifetimes and cache by splitting the `EnumerableOfKeyd` into cached key collection and transient `EnumerableOfKeyd`.